# How to Compare Array Size In Present Iteration To Array Size In Previous Iteration

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

`$array_size` is giving array size of array `$expkey` in each iteration. On each iteration I want to compare present array size with the previous array size. How to do this plus in on first iteration there  is no prev array size so it should not give some offset index. So how to do it. Thank you for help in advance.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    unset($_POST['submit']);
    unset($_POST['ew-language__en']);

    function printxml ($array)
    {
        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
        $xml->formatOutput = true;

        $last_index_ids = array();
        $parentid = array();
        $i_id=0;
        $x=0;

        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {

            $key = $key;
            //contains all the values of respective ids
            $attrvalue= $value;

            if ($array[$key] == "" || ctype_space($array[$key]) ) {
                $array[$key] = null;
            }
            //split unique input field names
            $expkey = explode("__", $key);

            $array_size=sizeof($expkey);

            echo"<pre>"; print_r($array_size); echo "</pre>";

            //first tag <ew-lang>
            $first_key =($expkey[0]);


            print_r($array_size);



        }
        $xml->save("file.xml");
    }
    printxml($_POST);

}
?>
```

on printing `$array_size` output is

```
1
1
5
5
8
8
11
11
8
8
5
5
5
5
5
5
1
1
5
5
5
5
```

`$array` is

```
 Array
(
    [global] => global
    [ew-language__en__0__phrase__actiondeleted] => Deleted
    [ew-language__en__0__phrase__actiondeleted__0__child_phrase__1234] => numbers
    [ew-language__en__0__phrase__actiondeleted__0__child_phrase__1234__0__child_phrase_1__abc] => test
    [ew-language__en__0__phrase__actiondeleted__1__child_phrase_2__5678] => numerics
    [ew-language__en__1__phrase__actioninserted] => Inserted
    [ew-language__en__2__phrase__actioninsertedgridadd] => Inserted
    [ew-language__en__3__phrase__actionupdated] => Updated
    [project] => project
    [ew-language__en__0__phrase__actioninserted] => Inserted
    [ew-language__en__1__phrase__actioninsertedgridadd] => Inserted
)
```

where as I am checking array size of `$expkey` which is

```
Array
(
    [0] => global
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 0
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actiondeleted
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 0
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actiondeleted
    [5] => 0
    [6] => child_phrase
    [7] => 1234
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 0
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actiondeleted
    [5] => 0
    [6] => child_phrase
    [7] => 1234
    [8] => 0
    [9] => child_phrase_1
    [10] => abc
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 0
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actiondeleted
    [5] => 1
    [6] => child_phrase_2
    [7] => 5678
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 1
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actioninserted
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 2
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actioninsertedgridadd
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 3
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actionupdated
)
Array
(
    [0] => project
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 0
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actioninserted
)
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 1
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => actioninsertedgridadd
)
```

Comment: @satyrwilder Can you help me with question ?

Comment: I can try. How are you calling printxml()? What are the contents of `$array` that are being passed in? Also, `$last_index_ids = array();`, `$parentid = array();`, `$i_id=0;` and `$x=0;` and `$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);` never get called. Where did they come from? Why are they present? The name of the function and about half of its functionality suggests it was not originally written to be used like this. Is that the case? `$array_size=sizeof($expkey);` - [`sizeof`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) is an alias of [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: yes its not the complete code as I am stuck with the sizes i removed the other details DOMXPath($xml); has nothing to do with array_size .

Comment: $array added . i have to compare size of  expkey array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try and store a before and after value after calculating final (`$array_size`):

```
<?php

    $arr[]  =   1;
    $arr[]  =   3;
    $arr[]  =   4;
    $arr[]  =   1;

    // This is just a hypothetical loop just to demonstrate concept
    // representing the loop: foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    foreach($arr as $array_size) {

            //******************************************************//
            // Do all your code that gets to to the final count here
            //******************************************************//

            $calculated =   $array_size;

            if(isset($check)) {
                    if($calculated < $check)
                        echo $calculated.' is less than '.$check;
                    else
                        echo $calculated.' is more than '.$check;

                    echo '<br />';
                }
            else
                echo $calculated.' is first'."<br />";

            $check      =   $array_size;
        }
?>
```

**Gives you:**

```
1 is first
3 is more than 1
4 is more than 3
1 is less than 4
```